# How to show posts from a any Facebook page (when I'm not the owner of this page)

Tags: facebook

I apologize if I don't use the correct terms. I'm unfamiliar with Facebook / Graph API.

I want to show posts from several Facebook pages, which **I don't own**.
I can contact the owners of each page and ask for some kind of permission / token.

Is such a thing possible (without setting an App per Facebook page)?

Comment: Define “show posts.” You can show any public post you have the URL for, using the Posts plugin. Or is this about automatically _getting_ the URLs to the most recent post(s) of a page? Then those page owners would need to login to your app and grant it access, so that your app can read their page feed.

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in getting the latest posts from several different pages, preferably getting the info in a structured manner (JSON etc.).
Do I need to setup a "Facebook app" for this?
What is the process of asking those admins for this access?

Comment: Yes, that needs an app then. The process of asking them is that you present them with a login button, that asks them to grant your app the necessary permission(s). Then you use their user token to request the list of pages they manage, and then the latest posts from each of those page’s feeds.

Comment: Does it require an App per page, or can I use a single app for multiple pages owned by multiple users?

Comment: No, you can handle all this with one app.